# Silence Cocoa error beep

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, keyboard, first-responder

I have a Cocoa application that captures keypresses through a custom view in the view hierarchy. This view implements the `keyUp` and `keyDown` methods, and the keypresses are received. Even so, Cocoa still insists on playing the system error sound/ding every time I press a key. Any solutions?

Note: Although I tried to make this view first responder, it didn't work. That may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have unsuccessfully tried to make the view the first responder, it's most likely because `NSView` returns `NO` for [`acceptsFirstResponder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/acceptsFirstResponder). You can have your `NSView` subclass override `acceptsFirstResponder` to return YES:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

That should eliminate the beeps. Alternatively, you could have the `NSView` subclass override `NSResponder`'s `performKeyEquivalent:` method to return YES, which should also eliminate the NSBeeps:

```
- (BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent *)event {
    return YES;
}
```

UPDATE:

Not sure what to suggest. I actually wrote a "Keyboard Cleaner Helper" app that's designed to basically do something similar to what you want. (I used it on my laptop when I wanted to clean the keyboard and didn't the hundreds of key presses to randomly rename files or result in repeated error beeps).

Sample project: http://www.markdouma.com/developer/KeyboardCleanerHelper.zip

Running that app, I can't get it to beep at all (notice calls are logged to Console).

Comment: It's `acceptsFirstResponder` now? Wow. I'm not at my Mac right now, but I'll try it and accept. Thanks for the answer to this annoying problem.

Comment: @Linuxios: what do you mean by "It's `acceptsFirstResponder` now?" What did it used to be? Or are you maybe referring to the method you were using to try to make the view the first responder?

Comment: I thought it was `canBecomeFirstResponder`. I'm at my Mac now, I'll give it a try.

Comment: No cigar I've done both, and neither works. CNN you think of anything else?

Comment: By the way, I got it to work by adding a NSTextView to my interface. Bizarre.

Comment: - (BOOL)performKeyEquivalent:(NSEvent *)event <- This works for me.
Thanks you.